# Using SQL Open Query on Oracle Server, Date overflow?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm querying an Oracle server using OPENQUERY. The issue I'm running into is when I execute my query, the date returned from Oracle. For example

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(ORACLE,
                        'SELECT * FROM ORACLE.some_table
                         WHERE date >'01-Jan-2016')
```

Will return a different number of rows than when I run the same query in Oracle. It also returns a date column with a large selection of dates listed as '4712-DEC-31'

Comment: I think the way dates are handled and stored is different between Oracle and SQL Server; you may need to cast the predicate using TO_DATE and the return date values as strings and then convert them back to dates

Comment: Try to use syntax like '2016-01-01'. Also `date` is not a valid field name. If that is the real name 1) fire the DB Designer 2) surround the the name with ""

Comment: Thanks! I was just using the date as an example of a field name, the actual field is not named date